# How to add navigation in footer like StackExchange?

Tags: navigation, footer

I want to add more number of navigation menu in footer area, how to do this?

For example:

There are four columns. Each columns has headings. Each heading has three navigation links.

First column

**Heading 1**

- menu 1.1
- menu 1.2
- menu 1.3

**Heading 2**

- menu 2.1
- menu 2.2
- menu 2.3

**Heading 3**

- menu 3.1
- menu 3.2
- menu 3.3

**Heading 4**

- menu 4.1
- menu 4.2
- menu 4.3

See below this page

For Ex:

**TECHNOLOGY**

- Stack Overflow
- Server Fault
- Super User

**Life/Arts**

- Photography
- Science Fiction

Example Screenshot

[image: StackExchange navigation footer]

EDIT:

```
register_nav_menus(array(
    'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu' ),
    'footer' => __( 'Footer Menu' ) 
));
```

I register two menu locations and display menus

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you done any searching? Are you familiar with WordPress templating, PHP, HTML, CSS?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee see above edit